# Specflow Hooks - Why do they need to be static?

Tags: c#, hook, specflow

I understand the utility of the hooks in C# Specflow, but why do BeforeScenario / AfterScenario and BeforeFeature / AfterFeature have to be static?

Answer (score 1):

Note that, contrary to what you assume in your question, `[BeforeScenario]` and `[AfterScenario]` can decorate non-static methods without any problem. As regards `[BeforeFeature]` & `[AfterFeature]` and also `[BeforeTestRun]` & `[AfterTestRun]`, according to the article [Advanced Specflow Shared & Scoped Bindings, Hooks And Step Reuse](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/specflow-bindings-hooks-step-reuse/):

> The bindings for these hooks should be static as the test **context has still not been set** before the test (and is not available after the test).

This also suggests that the `Hook` class with `[BeforeTestRun]` and `[BeforeFeature]` is instantiated **after** these methods are executed during a test run, and for this reason they need to be `static`. It is impossible to call non-static methods without having an instance first.

I modified the SpecFlow example project Calculator to test this theory and see in what order the different components of SpecFlow are used and instantiated. I've created the following classes:

- `Hooks`: defines a `[BeforeTestRun]` and a `[BeforeScenario]`
- `CalculatorContext`: example context class

I also used an [ISpecFlowOutputHelper](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/outputapi/outputapi.html) to print traces since the xUnit test runner does not allow `Console.WriteLine()`. I put traces into the constructors of the relevant classes and also inside the hook methods. As you can see, for the static methods it's impossible even to inject `ISpecFlowOutputHelper`, so I had to make use of an exception to test the order of creation of each instance:

`Hooks`

```
[Binding]
public sealed class Hooks
{
    private readonly ISpecFlowOutputHelper _specFlowOutputHelper;

    public Hooks(ISpecFlowOutputHelper specFlowOutputHelper)
    {
        _specFlowOutputHelper = specFlowOutputHelper;
        specFlowOutputHelper.WriteLine("Hooks()");
    }

    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void BeforeTests()
    {
        // _specFlowOutputHelper.WriteLine("BeforeTests()"); Unable to use DI in a static method
        // throw new Exception("BeforeTests() thrown an exception!");
    }

    [BeforeScenario()]
    public void BeforeScenario(CalculatorContext context)
    {
        _specFlowOutputHelper.WriteLine("BeforeScenario()");
        _specFlowOutputHelper.WriteLine($@"First Operation: {context.Operations[0]}");
    }
}
```

`CalculatorContext`

```
public CalculatorContext(ISpecFlowOutputHelper outputHelper)
{
    outputHelper.WriteLine("CalculatorContext()");

    Operations = new List<string>()
    {
        "+",
        "-",
        "/",
        "*"
    };
}
```

First, I commented the exception throw and debugged an example test. This are the traces shown in the TestRunner:

```
Standard Output: 
   -> CalculatorContext()
   -> Hooks()
   -> BeforeScenario()
   -> First Operation: +
```

[image]

This means that the very first thing that is instantiated is the `CalculatorContext`, whereas the class `Hooks` containing `[BeforeTests]` and `[BeforeScenario]` is instantiated later. It makes sense because `Hooks` has a dependency on `CalculatorContext` for the method `BeforeScenario(CalculatorContext context)`, but of course this dependency is only for the non-static methods.

Finally, if we comment back in the exception throw at `BeforeTests()`:

```
[BeforeTestRun]
public static void BeforeTests()
{
    // _specFlowOutputHelper.WriteLine("BeforeTests()"); Unable to use constructor DI in a static method
    throw new Exception("BeforeTests() thrown an exception!");
}
```

and debug the example test again, then:

```
---- System.Exception : BeforeTests() thrown an exception!
```

[image]

our Exception is thrown before any of the traces has been printed, which means that the static method marked with `[BeforeTestRun]` is actually executed before running all tests, and before instantiating the context and the hooks. In my experiment I have used `[BeforeTestRun]`, but the same applies to `[BeforeFeature]` and `[AfterFeature]`.

Beyond the theory, there's some real scenarios in which it might make sense to have non-static `BeforeTestRun`, as seen in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/706).

I also recommend you to read this other excellent article, [Dependency Injection and Context Injection In Specflow](https://www.testmanagement.com/blog/2023/07/dependency-injection-and-context-injection/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20SpecFlow%20domain%20just,this%20with%20%E2%80%9CContext%20Injection%22.), that has helped me a lot to understand this topic and prepare this answer.

Comment: It is written in the documentation: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Hooks.html

Comment: @GabrielaR, not all hooks must be static. Only the ones that specifically say so in the documentation.

Comment: @GabrielaR okay, now I understand it. The method decorated by ```BeforeFeature``` /  ```AfterFeature``` has to be static. Is this a theoretical question or do you have a scenario in particular where you would like to apply ```BeforeFeature``` /  ```AfterFeature``` to a non-static method?

Comment: It is a theoretical question. Is there a specific reason why it has to be static, or only because the documentation says so?

Comment: @GabrielaR please see my updated answer